# Are soft skills training adapted to neurodivergent people?

Tags: communication, soft-skills

Neurodivergent people (TSA, ADHD, etc.) typically have trouble with social interactions. Soft skills (for tech people for examples) are mostly all about communication.

- How to pass idea properly
- How to get/receive feedback
- How to manage people
  And so on

Are soft skills training sessions typically well adapted to neurodivergent people, or should those people seek training that addresses their specific needs more directly? And does such training exist?

Comment: I don't think workplace is well suited for neurodivergent people. There's a reason there's so few autistic people employed, and the ones who are employed burn out very fast and frequently. Mostly from dealing with neurotypicals and having to mask. This communication training might just further their masking, which then furthers the burnout

Comment: There's a lot more complexity to the story than just that narrative that autistic people struggle with employement. The Autistic spectrum alone is extremely wide, with significant numbers of people on the more mild end in productive employment. There are a lot of complexities here, where the question makes assumptions that further that narrative.

Comment: Neurodivergent people do not struggle to pass ideas properly. They struggle to present ideas in the manner and with the subtexts that Neurotypicals expect. This is a fundamentally different view. (Put a team of similarly neurodivergant people together, and they can be incredibly effective communicators, whilst looking like a complete mess to neurotypicals).

Comment: @TheEvilMetal, millions of people with ASD are employed, don't lump them all in with those with more severe symptoms.

Comment: What is TSA? Is that a common term? I am aware of ASD and AD(H)D, but not that.

Answer (score 11):

Neurodivergent people are all individuals with very different requirements. A limitation that applies to one person might not apply to another. An adaptation that works for one person might not work for another. So if any trainer claims that their training is adapted for neurodivergent people, of even a specific flavor of neurodivergence, I would be really skeptical about that.

However, good trainers in soft skill training should be able to adapt and make modifications and accommodations in their courses if they know about the special needs of individual participants beforehand. So I would recommend people who have special needs or different prior conditions than neurotypical people to contact the trainer before the training and discuss with them how the training could be adapted to be more useful and comfortable for them.

People who are unable to function properly in a work environment in general and would like to change that, might want to ask a psychotherapist for personalized advise to find a way to overcome their personal limitations in a way that works for them. A "one size fits all" softskill training might help, but it might not be all the help they need.

Comment: Your human factors group, if your company is big enough to have one, may also have some general suggestions in things like how to manage distractions. Support groups focusing on your particular areas of concern.are probably better resources for specific advice. I generally dislike "talk therapy", but it _is_ useful if you need help developing new coping strategies and sometimes that's all you really need.

Comment: Neurotypical people are also all individuals with different requirements. A good communications training course will apply fairly equally to all - how to recognize how the other person communicates best and adapt to that as much as possible.

Comment: Additionally, when looking at a more general corporate level, its worth taking into account that communication is a two way activity. Inclusion of neurodiversity can be a lot more successful when you admit that neurotypicals will have to adapt their communication with additional skills as well as neurodivergent individuals to meet the needs of a specific group of individuals (such as a team), rather than the assumption that their is a single 'proper' communication approach that applys to all groups.